# Парсинг строки по дате PHP

Tags: php, парсер

Помогите распарсить строку по дате.
Поступает текст где в начале каждого сообщения указана дата.
Могу ли я получить из этого массив где каждое значение начинается с даты?

```
02.09.2016 18:04:12, Петрова Юлия выполнил(а) задачу "Отразить визит к клиенту": Регион: Москва Количество точек: 1 26.07.2016 10:54:29, Петрова Юлия выполнил(а) задачу "Отразить визит к клиенту": Регион: Москва Количество точек: 1 20.07.2016 12:33:23, Петрова Юлия вернул(а) сделку на этап "Визит к клиенту"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = '02.09.2016 18:04:12, Петрова Юлия выполнил(а) задачу "Отразить визит к клиенту": Регион: Москва Количество точек: 1 26.07.2016 10:54:29, Петрова Юлия выполнил(а) задачу "Отразить визит к клиенту": Регион: Москва Количество точек: 1 20.07.2016 12:33:23, Петрова Юлия вернул(а) сделку на этап "Визит к клиенту"';
```

Просто разделить по дате (и убрать пустые элементы):

```
// значение дат теряется
$result = preg_split('/(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Разделить по дате и убрать запятые:

```
// значение дат сохраняется в массиве
$result = preg_split('/(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}), /', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

// группируем массивами [дата, строка]
var_dump(array_chunk($result, 2));
```

Comment: var_dump(array_chunk($result, 2));  не дает никакого результата

Comment: Если не даёт результата, надо смотреть, что попало в `$result`